# Spark History Server not starting

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I have installed CDH 5.4.7 on my 3 node cluster. After running the first job on Spark I checked for application history page. It was written as following

```
Event log directory: hdfs://****:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory

No completed applications found!

Did you specify the correct logging directory? Please verify your setting of 
spark.history.fs.logDirectory and whether you have the permissions to access 
it. It is also possible that your application did not run to completion or 
did not stop the SparkContext.
```

I checked the HDFS and found that `/user/spark/applicationHistory` was already there. But there was no entry inside that directory. That means no log has been written. I searched cloudera documentation page and found the article `Managing the Spark History Server` on the following link

[Managing Spark History Server](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/admin_spark_history_server.html)

As described I have added a Spark History Server and started it. Executed the following two commands for my user

```
$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown -R spark:spark /user/spark
$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 1777 /user/spark/applicationHistory
```

However, when I tried to execute the following command it gives `no such file or directory` error

```
$ cp /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

So, I went to the path `/etc/spark` and listed the files inside that. It showed something like this

```
conf -> /etc/alternatives/spark-conf
```

Neither I could create dir named `conf` because it is already there nor I can change directory to `/etc/spark/conf`

Also `service spark-history-server start` command gives `unrecognized service` error.

Kindly help! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue on Cloudera Quickstart VM 5.12.0 image and able to sort out the issue by following below steps:

- Stop the History Server:

> $ sudo service spark-history-server stop

- Set ownership and permissions on /user/spark/applicationHistory/ directory in HDFS and as follows:

> $ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown -R spark:spark /user/spark
>
> $ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/spark/applicationHistory

- Add below lines to /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf file to log the events:

> spark.eventLog.enabled=true
>
> spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/spark/applicationHistory

- Add below line to /etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf file to link YARN ResourceManager directly to the Spark History Server:

> spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://quickstart.cloudera:18088

- Start the History Server:

> $ sudo service spark-history-server start

Hope that it will be useful to others.